# Custom Transition - how to access "from" view when using "Over current Context" to present new VC modally

Tags: swift

So I have `firstVC` and `secondVC`. I want `secondVC` to slide in from the top (while `firstVC` slides down) (see picture).

[image]

A 'normal' segue would delete `firstVC` after the transition has been finished. I don't want that.

So in the storyboard, I set "Presentation" on the second VC to "Over Current Context".

But now I can't access `firstVC` and its view anymore (inside my custom transition class. In the method `animateTransition`):

`let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)!` throws an error (unwrapping an optional).

Why is that?

Comment: Did you come across any solution for this? If yes, please post it as answer. I have encountered same problem and would like to know the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find any solutions for this problem. I had to use another approach. I'm sorry

Comment: Can you share the approach or a link to any of it's reference so that I can get a little help.

Comment: With a different approach I meant that I chose to, more or less, completely change the UI so that I don't need to have this kind of transitions anymore :D

Comment: Oh! Okz cool! Thanks!